# I have a function that takes input TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9). But doesn't seem to like any of the input I'm giving it, which is also TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)

Tags: function, datetime, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a function that takes the input TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9). I also have a CTE with two different columns that return the date to the last 30mins. What happens when i do the conversion it takes it and converts it to char, so i have to convert it back to a datetime format. however, when i pass this through the function, i get this error: 'Processing aborted due to error 300010:391167117; incident 3384660.' I think it's to do with the datetime not being in UTC format, when i enter sysdate() in the function, it works as expected, but when i enter current_timestamp() it does not.

Below is the code along with everything i've tried:

```
--THIS IS THE FINAL TEMP TABLE
WITH TEMP
AS (
    SELECT CAST(SUM(sreg.ScrapQuantity) AS INT) AS Quantity,
        sreas.Name AS ScrapReason,
        (floor(date_part(epoch_second, sreg.ScrapTime) / 1800) * 1800)::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) AS DATETIME_MODIFIED_TO_HALF_HOUR,
        convert_timezone('UTC', (floor(date_part(epoch_second, sreg.ScrapTime) / 1800) * 1800)::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)) AS DATETIME_MODIFIED_TO_HALF_HOUR_2,
        srer.EquipmentID AS EquipmentID,
        srer.load_date AS load_date
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.ScrapRegistration sreg,
        RAW_CPMS_AAR.ScrapReason sreas,
        RAW_CPMS_AAR.WorkRequest wr,
        RAW_CPMS_AAR.SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement srer
    WHERE sreas.ID = sreg.ScrapReasonID
        AND wr.ID = sreg.WorkRequestID
        AND srer.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID
    GROUP BY --to_timestamp(floor(date_part(epoch_second, sreg.ScrapTime) / 1800) * 1800),
        (floor(date_part(epoch_second, sreg.ScrapTime) / 1800) * 1800)::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
        convert_timezone('UTC', (floor(date_part(epoch_second, sreg.ScrapTime) / 1800) * 1800)::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)),
        srer.EquipmentID,
        sreas.Name,
        srer.load_date
    )
--timestamp gives me        2021-12-02T10:00:00Z
--timestamp_tz gives me     2021-12-02T01:30:00-08:00
--timestamp_ltz gives me    2021-12-02T02:00:00-08:00
--manual entry              '2021-12-02T02:00:00-08:00'
--vcarchar gives me 1638439200
--select try_to_timestamp(temp.DATETIME_MODIFIED_TO_HALF_HOUR,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from temp --does not like format
--select temp.EquipmentID from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e, temp Where e.ID = (select * from table(cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime_test(temp.load_date, 0))) --this works
--select temp.EquipmentID from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e, temp Where e.ID = (select * from table(cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime_test('2021-12-02T02:00:00-08:00'::datetime, 0))) -- this works
--select temp.EquipmentID from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e, temp Where e.ID = (select * from table(CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST(temp.DATETIME_MODIFIED_TO_HALF_HOUR, 0)))  -- Invalid argument types for function 'CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST': (TIMESTAMP_NTZ(0), NUMBER(1,0))
--select e.id from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e Where e.ID = (select * from table(CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST((select DATETIME_MODIFIED_TO_HALF_HOUR from test_view_for_temp_table_delete_later), 0))) --Invalid argument types for function 'CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST': (TIMESTAMP_NTZ(0), NUMBER(1,0))
--select temp.EquipmentID from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e, temp Where e.ID = (select * from table(CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST((select convert_timezone('Europe/Paris', current_timestamp()) as europe_paris_time_zone), 0))) --this works
--select temp.EquipmentID from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e, temp Where e.ID = (select * from table(CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST((select convert_timezone('UTC', current_timestamp()) as utc_time_zone), 0))) -- this works
--select temp.EquipmentID from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e, temp Where e.ID = (select * from table(CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST((select current_timestamp()), 0))) -- this doesnt work
--select temp.EquipmentID from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e, temp Where e.ID = (select * from table(CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST((select sysdate()) , 0))) -- this works 
--select temp.EquipmentID from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e, temp Where e.ID = (select * from table(CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST((select convert_timezone('UTC', current_timestamp()::timestamp_ntz)) , 0))) -- this works
--select temp.EquipmentID from RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e, temp Where e.ID = (select * from table(CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST((select convert_timezone('UTC', current_timestamp())) , 0))) -- this works
SELECT TEMP.EquipmentID
FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e,
    TEMP
WHERE e.ID = (
        SELECT *
        FROM TABLE (CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST(TEMP.DATETIME_MODIFIED_TO_HALF_HOUR_2::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9), 0))
        ) --Processing aborted due to error 300010:391167117; incident 3301144.
```

The column i need to pass through is DATETIME_MODIFIED_TO_HALF_HOUR . the datetime output for that is '2021-12-02T09:30:00Z'

Below is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_AAR.CFN_GETSHIFTIDFROMDATETIME_TEST (dateTime TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9), shiftCalendarID int)
 
RETURNS table (shiftID int)
AS
$$
WITH T0 (ShiftCalendarID, CurDay, PrvDay)
AS (
    SELECT TOP 1
        ID AS ShiftCalendarID,
        DATEDIFF( day, BeginDate, dateTime ) % PeriodInDays + 1 AS CurDay,
        ( CurDay + PeriodInDays - 2 ) % PeriodInDays + 1 AS PrvDay
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.ShiftCalendar
    WHERE ID = shiftCalendarID
        OR (    shiftCalendarID IS NULL
            AND Name = 'Factory'
            AND BeginDate <= dateTime )
    ORDER BY BeginDate DESC
),
T1 (TimeValue)
AS (
    SELECT TIME_FROM_PARTS(
        EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM dateTime),
        EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM dateTime),
        EXTRACT(SECOND FROM dateTime))
    )
 
SELECT ID as shiftID
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.Shift, T0, T1
    WHERE Shift.ShiftCalendarID = T0.ShiftCalendarID
    AND (  ( FromDay = T0.CurDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= T1.TimeValue AND TillTimeOfDay >  T1.TimeValue )
            OR ( FromDay = T0.CurDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= T1.TimeValue )
            OR ( FromDay = T0.PrvDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND TillTimeOfDay >  T1.TimeValue )
        )
$$
;
```

Answer (score 1):

When a Snowflake query returns an error message matching this pattern:

```
Processing aborted due to error 123456:123456789; incident 1234567.
```

This is an unexpected error. In other words, an error occurred that the execution code was not expecting and has no handler to report an error that would be usual and expected by the user.

For example, if there's a SQL syntax error, the Snowflake code is expecting that, will trap the error and report it as a SQL compilation error. If the error is a division by zero, this is another expected error that the code will catch and report as divide by zero.

In this case, there may or may not be something that's an error between the SQL, data definition, and execution, but to find out exactly what it is you should open a case with Snowflake Support.