# Cluster by in TASK in Snoflake for CTAS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a task

```
create or replace task DB.SCHEMA.TASK_TASKNAME_DEVELOPMENT
    warehouse=W_WAREHOUSENAME
    schedule='USING CRON 0 10 * * * UTC'
    TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
    as create or replace table DB.SCHEMA.TABLE_TASKNAME_DEVELOPMENT
    cluster by (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
AS
SELECT * FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

I receive error

```
SQL execution internal error:
Processing aborted due to error 300010:3375338213; incident 6305946.
```

Can we not do CTAS with cluster by in Snowflake?

Thank You

Comment: That syntax works for me. Please refer to this answer about this error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74393205/i-have-a-function-that-takes-input-timestamp-ntz9-but-doesnt-seem-to-like-an/74395308#74395308

Comment: this worked for me, except what i did was changed the table name from "TABLE" to table1.

Comment: As a matter of good practice you should explicitly list your columns names, both in the table you are creating and for the tables you are selecting from. As written, changes in your source tables are likely to break this task